# How to install a virtual environment of Python in macOS

Tags: terminal, command-line, python, virtualization

First steps with Python, I am trying to run Python in a virtual environment in macOS.

I Googled "install virtual environment python mac" and got a link for [this](http://sourabhbajaj.com/mac-setup/Python/virtualenv.html).
When I typed in **Terminal**:

```
$ pip install virtualenv
```

I got a "command not found".

Is there a simple, well-explained (meaning for dumb, GUI-raised people like me) way to install a virtual environment for Python on macOS somewhere online? I would love if I didn't feel helpless every step of the way (long-distance goal: being able to run [this](https://github.com/NVIDIA/FastPhotoStyle)).

Answer (score 1):

I would install another python as this will allow you to put new packages in  consistent places. Apple's python as you note is missing pip. (and does not put packages where your linked page says) (Although the web site you show does have a [page](http://sourabhbajaj.com/mac-setup/Python/pip.html) telling you how to install pip)

I would also use python3 unless you have a good reason not to. Which again means install another python.

You can either install plain python from https://www.python.org/ This python includes pip but that needs to be upgraded as per [pip's website](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) This installation will have to be done under sudo.

Otherwise you can use a packaged solution e.g. [Macports](https://www.macports.org) or [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) - which I would use if you want a lot of C libraries or like [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/what-is-anaconda/) which is just a python packager.

(I  would normally say that Anaconda is the best for new users as it includes more ) However CUDA is low level code and the [USEAGE](https://github.com/NVIDIA/FastPhotoStyle/blob/master/USAGE.md) for the FastPhotoStyle does say that it has only been tested under OS: Ubuntu 16.04 So I would not expect it to run under MacOS.

Comment: Thanks! A lot of your answer made sense to me, I'm gonna try your solutions. As for the last sentence in your first paragrapg "$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py > get-pip.py"got me a "-bash: $: command not found"

Comment: You need to read so Unix tutorials I think. It is not in my paragraph - just a link to another page. The author is using normal style to show Unix commands. $ is the prompt (and normally a root prompt) and not part of the command. Anaconda does have a GUI to help you so might be easier. (But converting CUA libraries and usinf shared libraries will require learning more of UNIX)